# Get child from firebase on selected item on listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-studio

I have the following firebase database structure: 
[Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waJUt.png)
. In addition i have a listview that shows all the different trips. I would like to get the "TripID" child as a string when I click on a trip. How can I do that?

I have tried with the following code but i cant make it work.

Thank you in advance!

```
 final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference tripsRef = rootRef.child("Trips");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<String> listTime = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listTime);
                final ListView Time = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listtime);
                for (final DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String user = ds.child("UserName").getValue(String.class);
                    String arrival = ds.child("Arrival").getValue(String.class);
                    String departure = ds.child("Departure").getValue(String.class);
                    String time = ds.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
                    final Boolean TripID = ds.child("TripID").getValue(boolean.class);
                    String Trips = TextUtils.join("  |  ", new String[]{time, user,  departure, arrival});
                    listTime.add(Trips);
                    Time.setAdapter(adapter);

                    Time.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AvailableRides.this,RideSelected.class);
                            String entry = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView30);
                            String user = textView4.getText().toString();
                            String selectedFromList =(String) (Time.getItemAtPosition(TripID));
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE10,user);
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE8, entry);
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE9, TripID);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, declare right after your `listTime` list, another list like this:

```
List<String> idsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And inside the for loop, change the following line of code:

```
final Boolean TripID = ds.child("TripID").getValue(boolean.class);
```

with

```
String TripID = ds.child("TripID").getValue(String.class);
```

Additionally, also inside the for loop, add the following line of code:

```
idsList.add(TripID);
```

Right after this changed line:

```
String TripID = ds.child("TripID").getValue(String.class);
```

Then inside the `setOnItemClickListener()`, change this line:

```
String selectedFromList =(String) (Time.getItemAtPosition(TripID));
```

with

```
String TripID = idsList.get(position);
```

Don't forget the use the `TripID` variable in the other activity and in any other part of your code as a `String`, as it is in your database and **not** as a `Boolean`.